# Data returns correctly but won't display the returned data properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm currently struggling to view the returned data in a p and textarea element.

Here's the function I'm using, you can see that I am receiving each key from the comments node and getting the comment title and message and that works as it should...

```
function loadComments() {
    var comments =
        firebase.database().ref('/comments').once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                var childData = data.val();
                var childKey = data.key;
                console.log(childData.title + " " + childData.message);
                Elements.commentTitle.text(childData.title);
                Elements.commentMessage.text(childData.message);

                var clonedNode = $('.listItems:last').clone();
                $(clonedNode).insertAfter('.listItems:last');
                $(clonedNode).css({
                    display: "block"
                });
            });
        });
}
```

However when i try to view the data in the 2 elements, It will only show the title and message from the first node and that will duplicate depending on how many comments have been sent.

So for example, If say there were 5 comments, all with different data, so title and message were different. This is what you will see...

```
 Title
  Message

 Title
  Message

 Title
  Message

 Title
  Message

 Title
  Message
```

Also just in case it helps, here is the html code I'm using....

```
<div class="container listItems text-left w-75 justify-content-center" style="display: none">
        <p class="titleBody"><strong></strong></p>
        <ul><p class="commentBody"></p></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>` is invalid child of `<ul>`

Comment: What is `Elements`? Also as far as your logic goes....you clone the last one but never modify that clone

Comment: So your console.log statement is showing the correct data, but the elements displayed are not? It appears that you are just duplicating the first element without modifying it at all.

Comment: @charlietfl Elements is my custom object with all the selected elements inside just to make the code cleaner and yeah i just noticed that, thank you.

Comment: @Eric Svitok Yeah that was the problem but It's now been solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you clone existing element. You should replace data right after element has been cloned.

Code below fixes the problem you complained about.

```
function loadComments() {
    var comments =
        firebase.database().ref('/comments').once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                var childData = data.val();
                var childKey = data.key;

                var clonedNode = $('.listItems:first-child').clone();
                clonedNode.find('.titleBody:first-child > strong:first-child').text(childData.title);
                clonedNode.find('.commentBody:first-child').text(childData.message);
                clonedNode.insertAfter('.listItems:last-child');
                clonedNode.css({
                    display: "block"
                });
            });
        });
}
```